# 'Cannot find symbol' when sorting a stream of files using compareToIgnoreCase (JShell)

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol, jshell

Using **JShell** of *java 13.0.1* on *Debian Stretch*:

```
    import static java.nio.file.Files.*;
    var hm=Path.of(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    void p(String s) {System.out.println(s);}
    list(hm).sorted((a,b)->a.compareTo(b)).forEach(x -> p(x.toString().substring(hm.toString().length()+1)));
    list(hm).sorted().forEach(x -> p(x.toString().substring(hm.toString().length()+1)));
    "a".compareToIgnoreCase("A");
```

This all works (it lists the files in the home folder two times, and returns 0).

But when I enter:

```
    list(hm).sorted((a,b)->a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)).forEach(x -> p(x.toString().substring(hm.toString().length()+1)));
```

It leads to an error:

> Cannot find symbol, symbol: method *compareToIgnoreCase*.

Any idea what make *compareToIgnoreCase* to fail?

Comment: What type is `list(hm)`? I suppose it is not of type `List<String>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hm` is a [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html), thus [`list(hm)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#list(java.nio.file.Path)) returns a `Stream<Path>`. There is no method `compareToIgnoreCases(...)` in class `Path`. If one wants to use [`compareToIgnoreCase` from `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)), one needs to transform the `Path` to `String` first, e.g. by calling `toString()`:

```
list(hm)
    .sorted((a,b) -> a.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(b.toString()))
    .forEach(x -> p(x.toString().substring(hm.toString().length() + 1)));
```

Looking at what is done in the stream-chain, mapping the entries to `String` before further execution seems sensible:

```
list(hm)
    .map(Path::toString) // convert Stream<Path> to Stream<String>
    .sorted(String::compareToIgnoreCase)
    .map(x -> x.substring(hm.toString().length() + 1))
    .forEach(this::p);
```

(The code above assumes that `p` is an instance method of the `this`-object)